# How to reserve an autogroup percentage to one process in a script?

Tags: 20.04, scripts, cpu, process

So I have this code:

```
AUTO=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/sched_autogroup_enabled)
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_autogroup_enabled

setsid -w taskset 1 ../esx 100000000  8 3 0 0 0 0 2>/dev/null &

setsid -w taskset 1 ../esx 100000000  8 1 3 0 

2>/dev/null & wait

echo $AUTO > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_autogroup_enabled
```

So I would like the process 1 to have exactly the use of 77% and the second one to have 23%.

Is this possible to achieve editing the script?

I tried to do it, changing the value of the processes priority. But I'd prefer setting it.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @cocomac sorry, I put the wrong version, I'm using 20.04